# Simulate Minting Event In EmulatorTrace

Tags: minting, unit-test

My application has a minting script and a validator script that works together. I am using EmulatorTrace to test my application.How do i simulate a minting event in EmulatorTrace?

Answer (score 2):

There are plutus-contract tests, such as [MustMint.hs](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/blob/next-node/plutus-contract/test/Spec/TxConstraints/MustMint.hs), that demonstrate the use of each minting tx constraint: mustMintCurrencyWithRedeemer, mustMintValueWithRedeemer, mustMintCurrency & mustMintValue. Hope that helps.